# How to determine which host generated a core file?

Tags: core-dump

I have a setting where several machines share the same filesystem via NFS. Through a queueing system processing jobs can be submitted to several computing machines (with different properties).

Sometimes, a job will crash and leave behind a core file (with a name like `core.1234`).

Is there a way to find out which host generated that core file? What its hostname was?

(This is on Linux 64 bits, if it makes a difference).

Comment: I assume you run as the same user on each machine. If this cannot be determined afterwards from the core file, you could make different users on each machine and use a shared group with appropriate umask and permissions. Owner of the core then determines the machine uniquely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On an [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) system, a core file is almost certainly a valid ELF file.

```
 $ readelf -a core
 ELF Header:
 Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
 Class:                             ELF32
 Data:                              2's complement, little endian
 Version:                           1 (current)
 OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
 ABI Version:                       0
 Type:                              CORE (Core file)
 Machine:                           Intel 80386
 [...]
```

A platform specific number of "notes" are added to a NOTES segment so that a debugger can  find its way around, e.g. for Solaris see [core(4)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29042/core-4.html), and you'll note the `NT_UTSNAME` structure which contains the data structure from the `uname(2)` syscall. `elfdump -n` is the way to read that, but as far as I know Solaris is the only OS that does this (and I suspect only Solaris 11 `elfdump` works as hoped).

A simple, though slightly fiddly and not-guaranteed way is to try and fish the `HOST` or `HOSTNAME` variables (set by some startup scripts and shells, `bash` at least sets `HOSTNAME`) out of the core dump environment. You can do this with `gdb`, though you need the original binary:

```
$ gdb /usr/bin/sleep core
[... snip ...]
(gdb) print (char ***) &environ
$1 = (char ***) 0x600bf8
(gdb) print $1[0][0]@10
$2 = {0x7fffffffd9c9 "HOST=myhostname", 0x7fffffffd9d9 "TERM=screen", 
0x7fffffffd9e5 "SHELL=/bin/csh", 
[...]
```

This [prints a chunk of strings from the `environ` symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203455/why-i-cant-print-out-environment-variables-in-gdb). Though it's a horrible hack `strings | grep HOSTNAME=` just might work too.

So, short answer to "*Is there a way to find out which host generated that core file*" is: not easily, and not reliably on Linux.

FWIW, the relevant coredump code on Linux is in `fs/binfmt_elf.c`, and there is a hook to allow extra "notes" by way of [`ARCH_HAVE_EXTRA_ELF_NOTES`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=ARCH_HAVE_EXTRA_ELF_NOTES), currently only used on PowerPC.)

A better plan altogether is to [use sysctl to set the core file name](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt) on each client, as suggested by @jlliagre :

```
sysctl kernel.core_pattern="%h-%t-%e.core"
```

(`sysctl` and ferreting around in `/proc` are equivalent here, I prefer `sysctl` since changes can be kept documented in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and it's used on *BSD systems too.)

Comment: ``strings | grep HOSTNAME=`` is what I started using. This is interactive use; so it's OK if it fails a fraction of the time.

Answer (score 4):

You might run `strings core.1234` and find if the hostname appears somewhere. Some OSes like Solaris do put the hostname in the core header but as far as I know, Linux doesn't do it so the `strings` method would be unreliable with it.

A better approach would be to configure the `NFS` clients to put their hostnames in the core file names by setting the `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` file or some distribution specific configuration if `core_pattern` refer to an executable.